Solving Large size problems in industry: Tips and Tricks
What are the general tips and tricks to tackle a problem which is large (cannot be solved in reasonable time)? Business needs a "good" solution, and not necessarily optimal. Typical answers I get are column generation, benders composition etc. But, I am more interested in other non-mathematical tricks. I am aware of few. Would like to learn more, along with specific examples if any. For example:

Modelling tricks: Rolling time horizon, lazy constraints.
Programming: Pre-compute, parallelization.

PS: I need these for a tutorial I plan to give to OR practitioners.

Please, take a look at this link

Thanks @A.Omidi, thats helpful. I picked up couple of ideas from there now. Lets see if I can get more inputs like this from others on the forum.

There might also be the option of using problem-specific solvers (like Concorde for TSP) instead of generic MIP solvers.

See also the slides for A Guide to Identifying Good Near-Optimal Formulations for Hard Mixed-Integer Programs, which I presented in the tutorial track at the 2018 INFORMS Optimization Society conference. There are examples in four categories,

Breaking up
Throwing out
Cutting off
Reformulating

with 8 sample models to show how they work.

Large problems can frequently be partitioned based on time, location, product categories or other aspects. On a couple of projects with large MILP models, we got what I think were acceptable answers by chopping the problem into multiple smaller problems. In one case (placing pollution sensors in a body of water), we partitioned the area into cubes and solved each cube as a separate model. We incorporated a constraint requiring a sensor to be on/near each face of each cube so that the sensors in adjacent cubes could belong to the same communications network.
Another technique is to reduce the problem size by aggregation -- essentially removing unnecessary (or not entirely important) detail. For a MILP model assigning patients to physicians, we reduced the dimension significantly by lumping patients into disjoint categories and then replacing binary variables for patient-physician assignments with integer variables for the number of patients in each category assigned to each physician. Besides shrinking the problem size, that sort of aggregation has what is sometimes a side benefit: it leaves some decisions (for instance, which five patients from category C are assigned to doctor D) to the decision makers. Decision makers can sometimes resist adoption of models because they do not like having a computer tell them what to do.

Tricks we use for large scale problems in the Timefold Platform and/or our open-source Solver:

Orchestration: startup Docker pods on Kubernetes as needed to horizontally scale out as more datasets come in
Continuous Planning (= rolling horizon) to only solve the part of the horizon that is interesting. Typically that's 2 months, but in some cases it's up to 4 years.
Real-time planning (including warm starts)
Incremental score calculation if you're using metaheuristics
Probabilistic move selection if you're using metaheuristics
Dynamic termination of solver time. For example if the score is mostly flatlining
Map service to pre-compute, scale and cache distance matrixes
Scalable model design: Binary variables are not your friend.
Monitoring (platform): Transparant insights into which datasets solve well and until which point.
Logging (solver): When scaling trouble arrises, DEBUG and TRACE logs are life-savers.

All this enables our platform to handle large datasets with out-of-the-box models, such as a single dataset with 100k shifts and 10k employees, without any form of partitioning.
Once you go to a really large case (assigning a million people to covid vaccinations etc), additional scaling problems arise, but those are rare.

And if all this doesn't help, partitioning is also an option... (at the cost of solution quality)

Thanks Geoffrey. This is a useful list. Two quick questions/comments. 1) By Incremental score calculation, do you mean updating objective function only for the changes made, and not everything from scratch? 2) Besides logging, do you also support profiling using libraries like cprofile?


Yes, indeed. 2) I've done a lot of profiling and analysing flamecharts definitely helps, but profiling is a craft, and a tool with limits. Just like static code analysers, it will solve some issues but leave you entirely blind for others.


Thanks for sharing all the tips folks. I have tried to summarize those and few more from my end in this deck. https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/vh5t9y9nlseapw1b43ep2/OR-Tutorials-for-Practitioners-Session-10-Large-Scale-Optimization.pdf?rlkey=ekzjwu6cfs6hu4ek7d333dsm3&st=5kbvz5y0&dl=0
